# set the value read-only by java script in input

Tags: javascript, html

How can i set the value read-only by java script in input html (by class read)?

**HTML**

```
<input type="time" class="start" />

<select class="selectboxlist" >
<option>
<option>
<option>
<option>
...
</select>
```

**Tired following in Java Script**

```
if (selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 2 || selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 13 || selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 14) {         
            start.value = "00:00";  // works
            start.setAttribute.readonly = true;  // doesnt work
        }
```

Comment: *setAttribute* isn't a property, it's a method: `start.setAttribute('readonly', true)`. Or `start.readOnly = true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set attributes like this

```
start.setAttribute('readonly',true)
```

```js
function func()
{
var selectboxlist=document.querySelector('select');
if (selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 2 || selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 13 || selectboxlist.selectedIndex == 14) {   
var start=document.querySelector('.start')
            start.value = "00:00";  // works
            start.setAttribute('readonly',true)  // doesnt work
            console.log(start)
        }
        }
```

```html
<input type="time" class="start" />


<select class="selectboxlist" onchange="func()">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the input element and then set its readOnly property to true:

```
document.querySelector('.input').readOnly = true;
```